# Public virtual display has black screen

Tags: android, virtual-screen

I ran this example: https://github.com/android/media-samples/tree/main/ScreenCapture

And changed the display to be public so that I can access it using scrcpy:

```
mVirtualDisplay = mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("ScreenCapture",
                mSurfaceView.getWidth(), mSurfaceView.getHeight(), mScreenDensity,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC,
                mSurface, null, null);
```

When I open the display using scrcpy, I get a completely black screen, while on the preview it's showing correctly.

[image]

[image]  [image]

Why is it giving a black screen through scrcpy?

I'm assuming it's because the display is not secure (the warning "WARN: Display doesn't have FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS flag, mirroring can be restricted"), but there is no way for a regular app to create a secure virtual display, since the permission is for system apps only.

Any way to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

scrcpy shows a black screen because in this display (your defined display)
three is no presentation view.
pls used this code to display something on scrcpy.

```
import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.app.Presentation;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;

public class PresentationDisplay extends Presentation {

    public PresentationDisplay(Context outerContext, Display display) {
        super(outerContext, display);
    }

    public PresentationDisplay(Context outerContext, Display display, int theme) {
        super(outerContext, display, theme);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about_ui);
        ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeTaskLaunchBehind();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            options.setLaunchDisplayId(getDisplay().getDisplayId());
        }

        Log.e("TAG", "DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION  " + getDisplay().getDisplayId());

    }
}
```

And Use It :

```
  MediaRouter.RouteInfo route = ((MediaRouter) context.getSystemService(MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE)).getSelectedRoute(ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO);
        if (route != null) {
            PresentationDisplay secondaryDisplay = new PresentationDisplay(context,route.getPresentationDisplay());
            secondaryDisplay.show();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm writing a system application(android.uid.system) that create a virtual display and show the third-part app to the virtual display. Is any idea to make it come true? I tried some ways, but I still can't get the third-party application to display on the virtual screen.

Comment: Hi, if you want third-part app show on you system virtual display, you must set your display id when third-part want to start.

Comment: Thank you for your relay. Do you mean that at `startActivity`, I pass in `ActivityOptions.setLaunchDisplayId (...)` ? I did, but it didn't work. It is still displayed on the home screen (DISPLAY ID 0).